# Migrating from strut 1 to strut 2 how we will write the below tag

Tags: jsp, struts-1

Below is the code code that will redirect to the welcome global forward if getting success in login action class.

This tag is written in JSP page under some conditions that if session is valid then it will forward, otherwise it will forward
another logic redirect.

```
<logic:redirect forward ="welcome"/>
```

Comment: Ideally this work would be done in the action since it's not a view-level concern.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.